# QlikSense Set analysis SUM expression with explicit less than and ignore selections

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have an expression in QlikSense:

```
Sum({$<YEAR=,YEAR= {$(=YEAR(TODAY())-1)},MONTH={$(=NUM(Month(today()),'#'))}>}MOVES)
```

Which gives me the `SUM` of `MOVES` from `2018` (previous year) in `MONTH 6` (current month)

What I want is the `SUM` of `MOVES` from `2018` (previous year) with `MONTH`'s `1` to `6` up to current month.

I have tried adding `<` to the expression in different places but it returns nothing:

```
Sum({$<YEAR=,YEAR= {$(=YEAR(TODAY())-1)},MONTH<={$(=NUM(Month(today()),'#'))}>}MOVES)
```

&

```
Sum({$<YEAR=,YEAR= {$(=YEAR(TODAY())-1)},MONTH={$(<=NUM(Month(today()),'#'))}>}MOVES)
```

But they aren't returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this :

```
Sum({$<YEAR=,YEAR= {$(=YEAR(TODAY())-1)},MONTH={"<=$(=NUM(Month(today()),'#'))"}>}MOVES)
```

What is the format of your field Month, is it a number ?